# Не видит путь к файлам

Tags: java

Пишу на JAVA. Столкнулся с проблемой при экспорте файлов с eclipse. Прога в эклипс работает, но когда экспортирую путь к файлам не видит. 
Вот как пишу путь:

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Image/global.png"));
```

потом решил так, но не работает:

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("src/Image/global.png").getPath()));
```

Как можно написать, чтобы читал файлы внутри директории, т.е в самом `.jar`?

Пытаюсь но так и не получается. У меня есть движок который картинки загружает, хочу сделать но не получается.

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
    private BufferedImage image;
    public ImagePanel() {
       try {                
         image = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Image/global.png"));
       } catch (IOException ex) {

       }
    }

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); 
    }                   

}
```

При вызове движка добавляется картинка. Подскажите как изменить движок чтобы картинка добавлялась и после экпорта проекта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В Maven укажите папку с ресурсами и положите в нее вашу картинку
2. Загрузите картинку.

   ImageIO.read(getClass().get("button1.png"));

Comment: А как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Maven используете?

Comment: Нет, у меня программа подразумевает загрузку картинок в директорию и потом просмотр их по клику. А вот эта картинка вроде как небольшой заставки на пустое место. Я посмотрел что такое maven, думаю сложновато для меня будет, есть более простой вариант?

Comment: Какую IDE используете?

Comment: использую Eclipse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934796/how-do-i-add-a-resources-folder-to-my-java-project-in-eclipse

Comment: СПАСИБО ПОМОГЛО!

Answer (score 0):

Данный подход

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Image/global.png"));
```

означает что объект `File` будет получен по абсолютному пути на машине, на которой запущено приложение. Итак, если задача прочитать файл из ресурсов приложеных к приложению, то нужен подход с использованием `getClass().getResource`. Т.е. подход верный, только стоит уточнить, что путь к ресурсам должен быть установлен. Обычно это `src/resource`. Т.е. в таком случае `getClass().getResource("Image/global.png")` вернёт файл из `jar`, который находился во время сборки по пути `src/resource/Image/global.png`. Если нужен особенный путь, то это должно быть установлено дополнительно. Зависит от способа сборки приложения.